# Magento2: Ho w to get parameters order in last step checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout

I want add below code to last step chechout with confirmation order.

Anyone help how to get this parameters?

```
dmq('track', 'Purchase', {
transaction_id: 'ORDER ID',
value: 90.00,
shipping_cost: 19.90,
discount_code: 'KOD15',
contents: [{
id: 'PRODUKT_ID1',
name: 'PRODUCT NAME',
ean: 'PRODUCT BARCODE',
price: 10.00,
quantity: 1,
in_stock: true
},
{
id: 'PRODUKT_ID2',
name: 'NAZWA_PRODUKTU2',
ean: 'PRODUKT_EAN_ID2',
price: 20.00,
quantity: 2,
in_stock: true
},
{
id: 'PRODUKT_ID3',
name: 'NAZWA_PRODUKTU3',
ean: 'PRODUKT_EAN_ID3',
price: 30.00,
quantity: 1,
in_stock: true
}]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the order has been saved you have the order object in the checkout session (`\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session`).

Use the method `getLastRealOrder()` of the checkout session to get order data.

If you don't get all the data you need you may load the order model by the order_id from that data (or with session method `getOrderId()`) and use it's methods.

Update with code for detailed access of order data, order item data and product data:

```
//assuming you have the checkout session in the variable $checkoutSession

//if you already have an object manager in your context, use it instead
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$order = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($checkoutSession->getOrderID());
//order data --> see Magento\Sales\Model\Order for all available methods
//for example the order number
$order->getIncrementId();

//load the order items
$items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
foreach ($items as $item){
    //order item data --> see Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item for all available methods
    //for example product name
    $item->getName();
    //for example product sku
    $item->getSku();

    //if you need data from the associated product, load the corresponding product
    $product = $item->getProduct();

    //product data for any available product attribute
    $product->getData('[YOUR ATTRIBUTE CODE]');
}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: How can I get other parameters? Product name, Product order price, product barcode beetwen ''

Comment: OK, I have updated the answer. The only thing you have to do is to look for the order / order item fields or product attributes you need and change the code corresponding. I hope that answers your question.